# How to ask for a previous parameter (here: Scene) and act depending on the result?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, fxml, scene

On a specific scene I want to ask if the previous scene was X or Y. 
Depending on the outcome I want to load either X.fxml or Y.fxml after a button click.

I tried to inherit my MainViewController with one method but I failed at it.
My current approach just asks for the source (button) and depending on the button loads a specific fxml.

```
public class FinishViewController extends MainViewController {

    public void returnFinishHandler(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {


    if (event.getSource() == returnToConfigButton) {
        stage = (Stage) returnToConfigButton.getScene().getWindow();
        root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/view/configurationViewKds.fxml"));

    } else {

        stage = (Stage) finishButton.getScene().getWindow();
        root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/view/updateView.fxml"));
    }

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
    }
}
```

In the method I hope to ask for the previous scene and act on the result like I described previously.
In the best case I get some new perspective for a new approach.

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Why not set one event handler to `finishButton` and a different one to `returnToConfigButton` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an enum that stores your application state. Say you have a class called `AppManager` and inside there you created a public static enum `ApplicationState`. Then inside your `finishHandler`, you add an extra if statement to check for the current application state from your app manager.